# numpy / tensorflow vectorization of slices

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

I'm managing a big set of positions at different times, as a sparse matrix: an array of positions (the columns) and an array of times with the same size. E.g.

```
matrix = numpy.random.randint(2, size = 100).astype(float).reshape(10,10)
times = numpy.nonzero(matrix)[0]+1
positions = numpy.nonzero(matrix)[1]
```

Now i have to correct the positions with the speeds associated to a time. The problem is that being a sparse matrix, i have to expand the speed associated to a time, to every position at a given time (i.e. to every non-zero element in a given row). I know the indexes of first pisition at agiven time and the number of times `nTimes`
How can i vectorize this code (i.e. remove the loop)?

```
indexes = numpy.where(numpy.diff(times)>0)[0]+1
indexes = numpy.concatenate(([0],indexes, [times.size]))
nTimes = numpy.size(indexes)-1
speeds = numpy.random.rand(nTimes)

starts = indexes[:-1]
ends = indexes[1:]
expandedSpeeds = numpy.zeros(positions.size)
for i in numpy.arange(0,nTimes):
    expandedSpeeds[starts[i]:ends[i]] = speeds[i]
```

Edited in order to give a runnable example.

Comment: I find multiple things confusing in your example. What is `indexes`? If `expandedSpeeds` has a first dimension of size 3, that indexing in the last line is a bit weird. On the right hand side of the last line you basically have `speeds[i]` (except it's inside an array). Could you put a runnable MCVE into your question, please?

Comment: Yes you're right, I'm so sorry, I made a mess copying the code and trying to simplify the problem. The `indexes` array is `numpy.where(numpy.diff(times)>0)`. I'm gonna write a runnable example.

Comment: @AndrasDeak now you can try the code, it should work properly, thank you and sorry again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to *functionalize* the original approach and here's what I got -

```
def slices2arr_org(ar, starts, ends, N):
    out0 = np.zeros((N),dtype=ar.dtype)
    for i in np.arange(n_grp):
        out0[starts[i]:ends[i]] = ar[i:i+1]
    return out0
```

Now to vectorize it, we could make use of cumulative summation and some masking, like so -

```
def slices2arr_vect(ar, starts, ends, N):
    id_arr = np.zeros((N),dtype=int)
    id_arr[starts[1:]] = 1
    c = id_arr.cumsum()

    np.add.at(id_arr, ends[1:],-1)
    out = np.where(id_arr.cumsum()==0, 0, ar[c])
    out[starts[0]:ends[0]] = ar[0]
    return out
```

Here's a sample run to make things clearer -

```
In [677]: # Setup inputs
     ...: np.random.seed(0)    
     ...: n_grp = 5
     ...: N = 15
     ...: idx = np.sort(np.random.choice(N, n_grp*2, replace=0))
     ...: starts, ends = idx[::2], idx[1::2]                      
     ...: ar = np.random.randint(11,99,(N))
     ...: 

In [678]: ar
Out[678]: array([76, 50, 98, 57, 92, 48, 36, 88, 83, 20, 31, 91, 80, 90, 58])

In [679]: starts
Out[679]: array([ 1,  4,  7,  9, 13])

In [680]: ends
Out[680]: array([ 2,  6,  8, 10, 14])

In [681]: slices2arr_org(ar, starts, ends, N)
Out[681]: array([ 0, 76,  0,  0, 50, 50,  0, 98,  0, 57,  0,  0,  0, 92,  0])

In [682]: slices2arr_vect(ar, starts, ends, N)
Out[682]: array([ 0, 76,  0,  0, 50, 50,  0, 98,  0, 57,  0,  0,  0, 92,  0])
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i could never figure to use cumsum to solve the problem. If you want a little hint, np.ufunc.at unfortunately is even slower than a python loop (!). Your function works well too with a simple gathering with np.take or _fancy_ indexing (how numpy docs calls it xD): `id_arr[ends[1:]] =id_arr[ends[1:]]-1`. In this way che code runs twice faster ;)